# Fabric ./byfn.sh up returns error "...container_linux.go:348..." [win10 home edition]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am try to start an fabric network according to the doc "[Building Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html)" and the prerequisite docs.
However, when I execute the command ./byfn.sh up, it returns the error below:
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "no such file or directory": unknown ERROR !!!! Test failed
I have already tried to search for this error but with no luck.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me ...

System information:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.06.0-ce
  API version:  1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.3
  Git commit:   0ffa825
  Built:        Wed Jul 18 19:13:39 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false

37675@DESKTOP-JU1BJMT MINGW64 /c/Users/fabric-samples_120/first-network ((v1.2.0                                                                                                                                  ))
$ go version
go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64
```

[The complete output of byfn.sh up is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg4XL.png)

Comment: Can you post the entire output of "./byfn.sh up" ?

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into it. Don't know why I am not able to past the output txt directly, so I have to attach the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Please change the docker exec command to below

```
docker exec cli //bin//bash scripts/script.sh $CHANNEL_NAME $CLI_DELAY $LANGUAGE $CLI_TIMEOUT $VERBOSE
```

Add `//bin//bash` to the command so it points to the bash part of the container

Later in case if it happens to throw EOL exception, because shell doesn't understand DOS/Windows-like line endings
Edit in notepad ++ Edit > EOL Conversion > select Unix/OSX
Then it woks out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because your docker version is too new for release-1.2, 
As documented in 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/prereqs.html#docker-and-docker-compose
Try to pin to Docker version 17.06.2-ce, it could be better